# Dificuldade de gerar um arquivo bundle.js

Tags: javascript, babel

Estou testando o Babel
Para isso tenho um arquivo 'matematica.js' que por enquanto exporta apenas uma função

```
const soma = function(a,b){
    return a - b
}
export default {soma}
```

Esse função é importada no 'index.js'

```
import soma from './matematica.js'
var a = 10;
var b = 5;
onsole.log(soma(a,b))
```

Estou rodando o babel, desta maneira

```
babel ./index.js -o ./bundle.js
```

que gera o seguinte arquivo

```
"use strict";

var _mat = require("./matematica.js");

var a = 10;
var b = 5;
console.log((0, _mat.soma)(a, b));
```

porem no console aparece a seguinte mensagem

> bundle.js:3 Uncaught ReferenceError: require is not defined
>       at bundle.js:3
>   (anonymous) @ bundle.js:3

Alguém poderia ajudar mostrando meu erro na transpilação.

Comment: Babel é um transpilador, e não um module bundler. Para isso, você deve também usar ferramenta como o Webpack. Se você procura agilidade, o Parcel pode ser mais simples.

Comment: Acho que devias ter `export default soma` em vez de `export default {soma}`